# Any possible way in FlutterFlow to store values in List based in query

Tags: dart, flutterflow

Is there any possible way in FlutterFlow to store list of values based on query collection and to browse  this list one by one using 2 buttons next and back with text widgets?
Any help highly appreciated.

I tried everything nothing succeeds.